# file_get_contents() returning empty even though allow_url_fopen = On

Tags: php, apache, file, io

## Problem

`file_get_contents()` is returning an empty string for some reason.

## Code

#### index.php

```
<?php 
    $value = file_get_contents("http://foo.com/somefile.txt");
    echo $value;
?>
```

#### php.ini

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
```

#### http://foo.com/somefile.txt

```
69.00000000
```

## My Research

Generally when `file_get_contents("http://foo.com/somefile.txt")` returns an empty string, it is due to one of two reasons

1. `somefile.txt` is an empty file
2. `php.ini` has `allow_url_include = Off`

`$value` should now be `69.00000000`, but the function returns nothing.

## Question

Why is `$value` empty after the function call?

Comment: Is `$echo $value;` a typo?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I have amended.

Comment: Could `$value` be false? That means an error occurred.

Comment: If I echo $value, I get nothing, not false

Comment: Use `var_dump`. Echo won't give you anything useful in that instance.

Comment: file_get_contents may return `false`, not only a string value; so check for === `false`. Also enable error reporting to see if it really fails

Comment: Have you restarted server after enabling it ?

Comment: @shail, that could be it - I will do that now EDIT: No luck

Comment: check if default_socket_timeout is set to 0.

Comment: @jmsds default_socket_timeout = 60

Comment: check the php log if anything logged there. Also check if `url_fopen_wrapper` is on and curl is enabled. These are different options to test if everything is in place.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different kinds of 'empty'. Either the file is actually 0 bytes long (empty string), or [the call failed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), and the return is FALSE. To quote the docs:

> On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE.

Now, I don't know why your call failed, but it's likely to be logged in a webserver error log already, or you can convert these to exceptions to log them yourself.

A third alternative, advisable on a [development system](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), is to set `display_errors` in php.ini to make the problem visible:

```
display_errors on
```

This includes errors in the output, so that you can see them in the browser.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this:


checkRemote("http://foo.com/somefile.txt");

 function checkRemote($url)
{
    if(!checkRemoteLink($url)){
        echo 'bad link!';
    } else if(!checkRemoteFile($url)){
        echo 'bad file!';
    } else echo 'trouble!';
}

function checkRemoteLink($url)
{
    $file_headers = @get_headers($url);
    if (!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function checkRemoteFile($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if (curl_exec($ch) !== FALSE) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```